# Kentico 9 - Add content to an Editable Image Region (CMSEditableImage) programatically

Tags: kentico

We are looking for information on how to add content to an [Editable Image](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/CMSEditableImage) programatically (with the Kentico C# API). Essentially, the equivalent of this [Editable Region article](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/adding-content-to-an--editable-region--web-part-programmatically) for an Editable Image.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Victor

References:

- [CMSEditableImage Docs](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/CMSEditableImage)
- [Devnet Update EditableRegion Programatically](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/adding-content-to-an--editable-region--web-part-programmatically)
- [CMSEditableImage Class](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/9_0/api/html/T_CMS_Controls_CMSEditableImage.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You Sure Can**

Each individual editable cms page control is stored in the document's `DocumentContent` field and can be accessed using an indexer field. For example:

```cs
TreeNode document = DocumentContext.CurrentDocument;
string editableImageControlId = "EditableImage1";

// get the field value
string editableImageContent = document.DocumentContent.EditableRegions[editableImageControlId];

// set it to something new
document.DocumentContent.EditableRegions[editableImageControlId] = newValue;
```

**HOWEVER**

If you look at the `DocumentContent` field in `CMS_Document` in the database you'll notice that all of the content is XML. That's because each control is serialized into XML and then nested inside this field. Thus, in this case, the value of the `editableImageContent` variable is an XML string:

```xml
<image>
    <property name="imagepath">
        ~/Folder/ImageName.png
    </property>
</image>
```

I wouldn't recommend trying to modify this directly since there's no telling if Kentico would ever change this code, or the individual control would ever change its serialization output.

**But if you really must**

You've got a couple of options:

**1.** Per @josh, you could create a new control that wraps the existing one and do some method override magic so that the control continues to do the serialization on your behalf and you just modify it after the fact. However this requires that the control is currently loading.

**2.** You could just hard code the beast and deal with it if it ever changes (which it likely will). Try:

```cs
// get the node from wherever you need to get the node
TreeNode document = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().TopN(1).FirstObject;
var relativeMediaFilePath = "~/NewImage.png";
var xmlImage = string.Format("<image><property name=\"imagepath\">{0}</property></image>", relativeMediaFilePath);
var cmsControlId = "editableImage1";

if (document.DocumentContent.EditableRegions.ContainsKey(cmsControlId)) {
    document.DocumentContent.EditableRegions[cmsControlId] = xmlImage;
}
else {
    document.DocumentContent.EditableRegions.Add(cmsControlId, xmlImage);
}

// a little hack to get this field to be indicated as updated
document.SetValue("DocumentContent", document.DocumentContent.GetContentXml());
document.Update(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could clone the editableimage webpart and then work in the prerender or change the override for the GetContent() method and add your own part of the string or do a string replace and add your code.

Answer (score 1):

What is that you want to add to an Editable Image? - image path?! Not sure why you'd do that, but I'd take another direction: I'd add a field to a page type, which makes it much easier to work with through API. Having this field set up with API is should be quite easy to get it on the page... e.g. place editable image and use a macro to get field value.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
node.DocumentContent.EditableWebParts
```

and

```
node.DocumentContent.EditableRegions
```

collections to programmatically update editable content.

The best code example can be spotted at `\CMS\CMSModules\Content\CMSDesk\Properties\Advanced\EditableContent\Main.aspx.cs`

It's the dialog under Pages->General->Advanced->Edit regions & web parts.

[image: Edit regions and web parts]